# How to hide Nav bar in some react components

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I am trying to make a login flow using react. Routes are working as expected. But when I try to introduce nav bar, it is visible on all routes. I want to show nav bar only on selected components (only on profile and home route).

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

This is the Routes.js:

```js
export default class Routes extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path='/*/home'
          component={Home}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path='/*/login'
          component={Login}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path='/*/profile'
          component={Profile}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path='/'
          component={Main}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path='/*/'
          component={Org}
        />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

This is the App.js:

```js
<div className="App">
  <Nav />
  <Routes />
</div>
```

Comment: Link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47281850/how-to-hide-navbar-in-login-page-in-react-router

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide navbar in login page in react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47281850/how-to-hide-navbar-in-login-page-in-react-router)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Nav` component is being rendered in every view because it's located outside your views. There are a couple of options here:

1. Move `Nav` into home & profile only. This would make sense if you wanted to keep your `Routes` component the same.
2. Build a [higher-order component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) for rendering a view `withNav`. This would be the best option if you need to render more than just home & profile with a Nav on top. Let's say you have a modal that needs to have the exact same `Nav` (for some reason), it may make sense to build an HOC
3. Change your component tree to reflect the structure that you need. If only home & profile need the `Nav`, it may make sense to declare those two routes in a separate component.

Comment: I think your third option will work for me. For clarification, do you mean to say I should create a new routes component which will show nav bar and render it accordingly ?

Comment: I think it depends on your `Org`, `Main` and `Login` views as they sound similar to `Home` and `Profile`. Ask yourself, what level of abstraction can I create to group these views? The simplest one I can think of without reviewing your app is a `NavableRoutes` component for anything with the `Nav` and a `NavlessRoutes` for the other ones.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution. Check `useLocation` hook in "react-router-dom"

```js
function App() {
  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <>
      {location.pathname === '/' ? null : <Navbar />}

      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
        <Route path='/projects' component={Projects} />
        <Route path='/about' component={About} />
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Hiding the navbar in css, and Just show in Specific Component Using React-Helmet

```
 <Helmet>
      <style type="text/css">{`
    .navbar {
        display: inline
    }

`}</style>
    </Helmet>
```

Answer (score -1):

Below piece of code worked for me

```
 <style type="text/css">
      {`.navbar {display: none}`}
    </style>
```