# Reactjs render component without importing the navbar and style

Tags: reactjs

I am using react-dom-router to routes between my app components ,
I want to create a component (SeperatePageCompoenet) that when user navigate to the URL (http://localhost:3000/seperatePage), the compoenet will be rendered without using the imported "App.css" file, and does not include the  compoenet that is rendered in App.js component.

This is my index.js compoenet:-

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import "bootstrap-v4-rtl/dist/css/bootstrap-rtl.css";
import "bootstrap-v4-rtl/dist/js/bootstrap.js";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
//import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

App.js File:-

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import About from "./pages/About";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import Account from "./pages/Account";
import Contact from "./pages/Contact";
import NewPost from "./pages/NewPost";
import Test from "./pages/Test";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import Signup from "./pages/Signup";
import Post from "./pages/Post";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <NavBar />
      <div className="container rtl">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/create-new" component={NewPost} />
          <Route path="/contact-us" component={Contact} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
          <Route path="/account" component={Account} />
          <Route path="/post/:id" component={Post} />
          <Route path="/test" component={Test} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
} 
export default App;
```

The purpose of this, i want to view a text with full view page, without using the background-color that has been set in App.css file, and without including the navbar in the page.

Comment: I think you need to wrap it in a higher-order-component. See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47281850/how-to-hide-navbar-in-login-page-in-react-router or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53097610/how-to-hide-nav-bar-in-some-react-components is of any help

Comment: @zirmax, i will take a look at it

Comment: @zirmax, it worked for me , except that background-color is still using the one that set in App.css file, even though i've shifted the import App.css from index.js to  App.js

Comment: I guess the css is accessible for all your app, so you may need to overwrite it or only apply it to certain elements with a class selector. Easiest solution is to just overwrite your one components style with the background-color you want

Comment: @zirmax  have apply the style to a certain elements, now everything works fine, thanks. can you post your answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap it in a higher-order-component. See [How to hide navbar in login page in react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47281850/how-to-hide-navbar-in-login-page-in-react-router) or [How to hide Nav bar in some react components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53097610/how-to-hide-nav-bar-in-some-react-components)

Since your css is available for all or your app, I suggest to simply overwrite the style for your `SeperatePageComponent`